# Sonoff switches on Google Home - Cascade Router configuration?

Tags: smart-home, google-home, routers, sonoff

I had my Sonoff switches working fine on my rental FTTH modem then I bought Google Nest Wifi. Only my kitchen lights connect to the "blended" wifi, the rest of them won't show up on Google home (same models too). So, after killing an entire day successfully getting all switches running on my rental using various authentication schemes, then swapping in the Google router with same IP, SSID, password, etc, I get nothing but the kitchen.

Note: The kitchen switch has been installed MONTHS before the other ones so I may have done something slightly different in configuring it back then. All the switches were purchased together, and all have the latest firmware update (with LAN mode and inching).

I am NOT ripping out all my switches.

Is there a way to cascade my old router onto the Google Nest WiFi so my switches only see the 2.4GHz router, and everything else sees Google, but they are "on the same network" as that phrase applies to gGoogle Home and EweLink?

The Arris router has an ONT WAN terminal and 4 gigabit ethernet ports.

If the kitchen didn't work I would think it's a fundamental compatibility issue. But one switch works fine, so that's not it.